# Examine processes and threads of a program in the terminal

Tags: command-line, process

I would like to know if it is possible to view a running program entirely on terminal. What I mean is, as the program is being run with its own interface in desktop, can we also actually view all real time processes and threads that are being executed by the program in terminal.

If this is possible, then how can it be done? It would be really cool to view a real running program in its "skeletal version" via terminal.

Thank you.

Comment: `top` use that.

Answer (score 0):

`top` is display linux processes.
More detail about `top`. Command `man top`

Answer (score 0):

List of all proccesses displays

```
ps aux
```

Answer (score 0):

The "skeletal" view of programs can be given by `pstree` command.

I suggest you use `pstree -p` to include PID of each process.

To filter out a specific app, use `grep` in conjunction with `-A` flag, to show context after the matched string or `-C` to match context around the string. For example `pstree -p | grep 'virtualbox' --color -A 4` to show 4 lines after virtualbox.

For cleaner output  find out PID of a process, and run `pstree` with `-H` flag.

Example:

```
$ pstree -H $(pidof mksh)                                                                                 
mksh─┬─VirtualBox───5*[{VirtualBox}]
     └─pstree
```

[Here's](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-pstree-command-examples-shows-running-processestree/) a good tutorial for more info.